# Resolving paths in TypeScript outDir

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I'm writing a UI page object model testing project in TypeScript and I'm trying my best to avoid hideous nested imports.

I found the `paths` object for the `.tsconfig` file that fixes the issue in `.ts` files, but, because I compile into an `outDir`, my compiled `.js` files cannot resolve the module path.

I develop in a `model` directory and compile into a `src` directory.

I've set up my `.tsconfig` file as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "src/",
    "baseUrl": "./model/",
    "paths": {
      "general.utils": [ "lib/general/general.utils" ],
      "pretest.setup": [ "lib/pretest.setup/pretest.setup" ],
      "tpapi": [ "lib/tpapi/tpapi" ],
      "*": [ "*" ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

That `paths` allows me to

`import { chooseRandomValueFrom } from 'general.utils';`

from a `.ts` file that is in `model`, but won't resolve in a `.js` file in `src`.

This is an `npm` type project that is run with `npm test`. That command executes a script that compiles, runs tests from, and deletes the `src` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run compile:ts
node_modules/webdriverio/bin/wdio
npm run clean:ts
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I have been struggling with it for hours. Can not find information about this topic.

Comment: @CarlosLanderas I added my solution below. I wouldn't call it solved, but I've gotten used to it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to deal with this is to have a collector/exporter file that exports everything from the files that it collects from.

For examples if I have 5 files that have different types of utilities in them, I would name them appropriately, then collect them all in a collector/exporter file called `utilities`.

In the `utilities` file, it's just lines that look like

```
export * from 'path/to/file1
export * from 'path/to/file2
export * from 'path/to/file3
```

Then I can import only from the collector/exporter file.

It's not great, but it's a little better than doing nothing at all.