# Using paths in TypeScript in a NodeJS project

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

I'm trying to use the `paths` property in `tsconfig.json` in a NodeJS project.

In `tsconfig.json` I have something like this:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@myApp/server/*": [
    "server/src/*"
  ],
  "@myApp/common/*": [
    "common/src/*"
  ]
},
```

Running `tsc` outputs all JS files as expected, but they retain the `@myApp...` imports. As a result, `node` won't run as it can't resolve all modules having as path `@myApp...`.

I can't find a way to convert the `paths` I've set in `tsconfig.json` to a value that can be used by `node`. I've only found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407342/resolving-paths-in-typescript-outdir), but it's quite outdated and it does not lead to a clean solution.

Do we have a way to transpile TS to JS in a way in which we are able to use `paths`?

Comment: why you are using baseUrl to "../" instead "."

Comment: @AvinashMaurya typo, I've edited the question :-)

Comment: And I am sure that you are aware of the fact that baseUrl is relative to the location of 'tsconfig.json'.
can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes of course. As I said, typescript is working fine, the setup in `tsconfig.json` is correct. The problem is that the absolute `paths` defined in `tsconfig.json` dont't work in JS, and I'm looking for a way to convert them to relative paths.

Comment: what is the command that you are using to transpile ts code?

Comment: It's specified in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until today I was using [tspath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tspath) as suggested in the accepted answer, but I started to get some issues with relative paths having as `baseUrl: '../'`.

I switched to a `webpack` based approach, with this `webpack.config.ts` config:

```
import { TsConfigPathsPlugin } from 'awesome-typescript-loader';
import * as fs from 'fs-extra';
import { join } from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';

const packageConfig = fs.readJSONSync('./package.json', { encoding: 'utf-8' });

const externals = {};
for (const packageName in packageConfig.dependencies)
  externals[packageName] = packageName;

const serverConfig: webpack.Configuration = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [
      new TsConfigPathsPlugin({ configFileName: 'tsconfig.json' })
    ]
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  },
  externals,
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: '[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(`Copyright © 2018-${new Date().getFullYear()} BOHR. All rights reserved.`)
  ],
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-default-export
export default [serverConfig];
```

Note the imports, you will need to add few packages to use this configuration.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone out here is using with nodejs and `tsconfig-paths`. You can use the following commands to make the absolute paths work:

```
// With ts-node    
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.js

// With node    
node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/main.js
```

Got this from here:
https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths/issues/61

Answer (score 1):

I've found this `npm` package that converts all absolute paths to relative paths: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tspath.

Running `tsc` will produce the files with the absolute paths (e.g. `@myApp/server/my-library`). Then run `tspath` will convert all paths to the relative path.

Answer (score -1):

Why won't you just use the `path` module in the code and resolve the path to rest of the directories relative to the one where you started the server from?

Take a look at the line 6 in this example:
https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/blob/master/code-samples/Angular6/chapter12/server/rest-server-angular.ts.

The `__dirname` points at the directory where the server was started from, and `public` is a subdirectory of this directory. I didn't use the `paths` option of tsc.

Comment: Take a look at this post, https://goenning.net/2017/07/21/how-to-avoid-relative-path-hell-javascript-typescript-projects/ :-)